# dynamic styled components with mapped data

Tags: reactjs, next.js, styled-components

I'm trying to pull in a JSON of data that looks basically like this inside the json:

```js
"items": [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "title": "data header one",
    "bgColor": "dark",
    "buttonColor": "red",
    "shadow": false,
    "offset": 1,
    "padding": 0,
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "title": "data header two",
    "bgColor": "light",
    "buttonColor": "black",
    "shadow": false,
    "offset": 1,
    "padding": 0,
  }
]
```

And I'm trying to map this data inside a next.js functional component by using `map()`.

I'm struggling to see how to pass the `items` data such as "padding" or "buttonColor" or "bgColor" back into my styled components outside of the returned render. Is there a way to without using inline styles?

My return is set up like this:

```js
return (
  <>
  {items.map(({id, title, bgColor, buttonColor, shadow, padding}) => {
    return (
    <Cta key={id}>
      <Div>
      {title}
      </Div>
    </Cta>
    )}}
  </>
);
```

And my styled components is set up like this:

```js
const Cta = styled.div`
  background: ${bgColor};
  h4 {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: ${padding}px;
  }
`;
```

I've cut down the code so pay no mind to the data that isn't used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can use object properties for styling:

```js
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

export default function App() {
  const Cta = styled.div`
    background: ${props => props.bgColor};
    h4 {
      color: blue;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding: ${props => props.padding}px;
    }
  `;

  const elements = items.map(item => (
    <Cta key={item.id} bgColor={item.buttonColor} padding={item.padding}>
      <h4>Heading</h4>
      {item.title}
    </Cta>
  ));

  return <div className="App">{elements}</div>;
}

const items = [
  {
    id: "1",
    title: "data header one",
    bgColor: "dark",
    buttonColor: "red",
    shadow: false,
    offset: 1,
    padding: 10
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    title: "data header two",
    bgColor: "light",
    buttonColor: "black",
    shadow: false,
    offset: 1,
    padding: 0
  }
];
```

Here you can read more about passing data for styling using component's `props`: https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props

Comment: From the styled-components docs : "By declaring a styled component inside the render method of a react component, you are dynamically creating a new component on every render." (https://styled-components.com/docs/faqs#why-should-i-avoid-declaring-styled-components-in-the-render-method)